# Laravel: Background image will not appear

Tags: html, css, laravel, background

Right, so I'm trying to add a background image to my website. However, The image just won't appear. The path is correct but it just comes up blank when I load the page. Do you have to do something special to the path in Laravel for it to work? I am also using a master blade file which all other views extend, I'm not sure if this affects it.

Here is my CSS:

```
html {
    background: url("/storage/background/background_1.jpg");
}
```

Comment: I added style tags in the head of the master blade file and I used the asset() function, which fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not able to find the image because /storage is not accessible from the server. How to fix it is to make a symlink via the artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Or you could ofcourse store your image in public/img/yourimage.png and call it like this:

```
 html {
   background-image: url("/img/yourimage.png");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
style=" background:url('<?php echo "/yourFolderOfImage/$item->item_img1" ?> ')"
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding the style of the background image on the head section of the page. works for me.